# How to receive an event at the END of a page transition with jquery mobile

Tags: events, size, jquery-mobile, transition

Context :
I am trying to calculate the available vertical unused space on a jquery mobile page and use the result to size an element to use the maximum available space.

I can not start the calculation BEFORE the page has finished transitioning IN because the height of header, footer and content elements is set to 0 when the page is not visible.

I use the pageshow event to detect when the page transition is finished and do my calculation but found that the height of the footer is still 0 when the transition should be finished while it is in fact of 51px. also the page height return a height significantly smaller than the window or document height which is not the case once the transition is fully executed.

I have the impression that at the moment the pageshow event is triggered the page transition is in fact incomplete while according to the documentation it should be fired only once completed, aka all elements should have their final height.

Anybody know better or can point out some obvious mistake my understanding of this event ?

I have for now solved my problem by setting hard coded values but would much prefer to write a generic function that would work.

My code trimmed down :
Exert of the HTML page :

```
...
<div data-role="page" id="pWhereAmI">
    <div data-role="header"  data-id="mainHeader" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Where Am I ?</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="map-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>Position Unknown</li>
            <li id="map_canvas"></li>
            <li>Center the map</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-id="mainFooter" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#pLogin" id="home" data-transition="fade" data-icon="custom"><small>Login</small></a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page pWhereAmI -->
...
```

Exert of the javascript code :

```
$('#pWhereAmI').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    pageFreeHeight = pageFreeHeight_calc('#pWhereAmI');
    map_canvasHeight = $('#map_canvas').height() + pageFreeHeight;
    $('#map_canvas').height(map_canvasHeight);
});
```

The function called at pageshow event time :

```
function pageFreeHeight_calc(pageSelector) {
    if($(pageSelector).height != null) {
        pageHeight = $(pageSelector).height();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
    if($(pageSelector+' [data-role|="header"]').outerHeight(true) != null) {
        headerHeight = $(pageSelector+' [data-role|="header"]').outerHeight(true);
    }
    else {
        headerHeight = 0;
    }
    if($(pageSelector+' [data-role|="content"]').outerHeight(true) != null) {
        contentHeight = $(pageSelector+' [data-role|="content"]').outerHeight(true);
    }
    else {
        contentHeight = 0;
    }
    if($(pageSelector+' [data-role|="footer"]').outerHeight(true) != null) {
        footerHeight = $(pageSelector+' [data-role|="footer"]').outerHeight(true);
    }
    else {
        footerHeight = 0;
    }
    return pageHeight - headerHeight - contentHeight - footerHeight;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I modified it a little but your code looks good to me. Here is a live example of what I have:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/gkPAG/22/
- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/gkPAG/28/ <-- Display elements heights after adjustments

JS:

```
$('#pWhereAmI').live('pageshow',function(event, ui) {
    canvasHeight     = $('#map_canvas').height(); // initialize the canvas height
    pageFreeHeight   = pageFreeHeight_calc('#pWhereAmI');
    map_canvasHeight = canvasHeight + pageFreeHeight;
    $('#map_canvas').height(map_canvasHeight).page();
});

function pageFreeHeight_calc(pageSelector) {
    var pageHeight     = null;
    var headerHeight   = 0;;
    var contentHeight  = 0;
    var footerHeight   = 0;

    if($(pageSelector).height != null) {
        pageHeight = $(pageSelector).height();
    }

    if($(pageSelector+' [data-role|="header"]').outerHeight(true) != null) {
        headerHeight = $(pageSelector+' [data-role|="header"]').outerHeight(true);
    }

    if($(pageSelector+' [data-role|="content"]').outerHeight(true) != null) {
        contentHeight = $(pageSelector+' [data-role|="content"]').outerHeight(true);
    }

    if($(pageSelector+' [data-role|="footer"]').outerHeight(true) != null) {
        footerHeight = $(pageSelector+' [data-role|="footer"]').outerHeight(true);
    }

    alert(
        'pageHeight: ' + pageHeight + "\n" +
        'headerHeight: ' + headerHeight + "\n" +
        'contentHeight: ' + contentHeight + "\n" +
        'footerHeight: ' + footerHeight + "\n" +
        'returnValue: ' + (pageHeight - headerHeight - contentHeight - footerHeight) 
    );
    return pageHeight - headerHeight - contentHeight - footerHeight;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#pWhereAmI">Where am I</a></li>             
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="pWhereAmI">
    <div data-role="header"  data-id="mainHeader" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Where Am I ?</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="map-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>             
        </ul> 
        <br />
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>Position Unknown</li>
            <li id="map_canvas"></li>
            <li>Center the map</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-id="mainFooter" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#pLogin" id="home" data-transition="fade" data-icon="custom"><small>Login</small></a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page pWhereAmI -->
```

Comment: Hi Phil, I looked at your changes in code and did not really see anything that would explain why in your modified code the footer height is properly returned, but I did notice that the reported page height is not returned properly the first time I navigate to the WhereAmI page. The second time though it is, allowing a proper calc of the space available.This still point at the showpage event being fired too early. What is the .page() for, did not find it in the docs. +1 for getting me a step nearer to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: .page() refreshes the jQM markup/controls for dynamic content. You could also try the new create trigger like this: .trigger('create')

Comment: I think it's displaying the correct value for that time in the process. It's the order of operations. First you "pageFreeHeight   = pageFreeHeight_calc('#pWhereAmI');" this alerts/displays the heights but then you adjust the canvas size "map_canvasHeight = canvasHeight + pageFreeHeight;" this changes the pageHeight after we have already displayed the alert. I added another alert after the canvas resize to show that it's the correct size

Comment: Hi Phil, Not sure why I should trigger my own event. Also to answer your second message I don't think that JQM show the right hight for the time of the process, the process is triggered by the page show event. The JQM doc state the following : "Triggered on the page being shown, after its transition completes." Obviously the transition is not completed if the final size is not set and the navbar is not yet available, at least that's the way I understand it.

Comment: I agree with you about the page show event but you are resizing the canvas after the page show event so the page size will change when you do this. maybe try the before page show event?

Comment: Hi Phil, Before the pageshow event the elements in the page have 0 height. It must be part of the strategy to have multiple pages in one html document, the only moment I can adjust is after the page is fully visible, which is anyway not ideal because on slow device the readjustments are quite visible.

Comment: what about using pagebeforeshow instead of pageshow? http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/gkPAG/30/ the alerts might be off but I think readjustments would be complete before the page is shown